# Unable to activate "(more)" link

Tags: redmine

I seem unable to activete Issue editing.

I am aware of [[http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineIssues#Editing-an-existing-issue]], but something is wrong.

I am Manager on the project (same behavior even if I login as "admin") and I checked it includes the "Edit Issues" permission.
In spite of that the "(more)" link does never appear.

Another (maybe significant) deviation from standards is I do *_not_* have the "Update" link; I have an "Edit" link instead. Complete list of links is (note missing "Duplicate" and "Move"):

```
Feature #2                      Edit Log time Watch Copy Delete
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any specific setting to check?

My installation is as follows:

```
root@redmine www/redmine# RAILS_ENV=production script/about

sh: 1: darcs: not found
sh: 1: cvs: not found
Environment:
  Redmine version                2.6.1.stable
  Ruby version                   1.9.3-p194 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.21
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.6.17
  Mercurial                      2.2.2
  Bazaar                         2.6.0
  Git                            1.7.10.4
  Filesystem
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_dmsf                   1.4.9 stable
root@redmine www/redmine#
```

TiA
Mauro

Comment: You do not appear to actually be having the problem you claim to be having. You actually can edit issues. The problem is that the wiki is out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record:

Michael Hampton is right, even if not formally so. Thanks.

It turns out I seem "Unable to activate “(more)” link" because that link is no more.
Just "Edit"ing the Issue is now enough to activate old "Update", including "more" functionality.

I simply failed to spot the small pencil icon (no text) near "Description".

Wiki needs updating, beware.